# Gen: How to combine multiple generative function traces in a higher-order generative function?

Tags: julia, inference, generative, probabilistic-programming, generative-programming

I'm going through the "Introduction to Modeling in Gen" Notebook at https://github.com/probcomp/gen-quickstart

Section 5 (Calling other generative functions) asks to "Construct a data set for which it is ambiguous whether the line or sine wave model is best"

I'm having a hard problem understanding how I work with the traces (and returns) of the component functions to create a meaningful higher-order trace that I can use.

To me the most straightforward "ambiguous" model is `line(xs).+sine(xs)`. So I `Gen.simulate`ed `line` and `sine` to get the traces and adding them together, like this:

```py
@gen function combo(xs::Vector{Float64})
    my_sin = simulate(sine_model_2,(xs,))
    my_lin = simulate(line_model_2,(xs,))
    if @trace(bernoulli(0.5), :is_line)
        @trace(normal(get_choices(my_lin)[:slope], 0.01), :slope)
        @trace(normal(get_choices(my_lin)[:intercept], 0.01), :intercept)
        @trace(normal(get_choices(my_lin)[:noise], 0.01), :noise)        
    else
        @trace(normal(get_choices(my_sin)[:phase], 0.01), :phase)
        @trace(normal(get_choices(my_sin)[:period], 0.01), :period)
        @trace(normal(get_choices(my_sin)[:amplitude], 0.01), :amplitude)
        @trace(normal(get_choices(my_sin)[:noise], 0.01), :noise)
    end
    combo = [get_choices(my_sin)[(:y, i)] + get_choices(my_lin)[(:y, i)] for i=1:length(xs)]
    for (i, c) in enumerate(combo)
        @trace(normal(c, 0.1), (:y, i))
    end
    end;
```

This is clearly wrong and I know I'm missing something fundamental in the whole idea of traces and prob programming in Gen.

I'd expect to be able to introspect sine/line_model's trace from within combo, and do element-wise addition on the traces to get a new trace. And not have to randomly pick a number *close* to :intercept, :phase, etc. so I can include it in my trace later on.

By the way, when I do:

```
traces = [Gen.simulate(combo,(xs,)) for _=1:12];
grid(render_combined, traces)
```

I get 
[image: failed attempt at function]

Please help thanks!

Comment: You might want to ask this on the repo since Gen is quite brand new and so not many people here will know it yet.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisRackauckas I asked on the Repo -> Issues but it's not the correct place to do that. Hopefully I'll get some guidance as I keep going through the tutorials

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi there — thanks for your interest in Gen! :)

**Addresses of the combined model's trace**

The combined model from the tutorial looks like this:

```
@gen function combined_model(xs::Vector{Float64})
    if @trace(bernoulli(0.5), :is_line)
        @trace(line_model_2(xs))
    else
        @trace(sine_model_2(xs))
    end
end;
```

Its traces will have the following addresses:

- `:is_line`, storing a Boolean indicating whether the generated dataset was linear or not.
- Any addresses from `line_model_2` or `sine_model_2`, depending on which was called.

Note that traces of both `line_model_2` and `sine_model_2` contain the addresses `(:y, i)` for each integer `i` between `1` and `length(xs)`. Because of this, so will `combined_model`'s traces: these are the addresses representing the final sampled `y` values, regardless of which of the two processes generated them.

**Constructing a new dataset**

The question to "construct a data set for which it is ambiguous whether the line or sine wave model is best" does not require writing a new generative function (with `@gen`), but rather, constructing a list of `xs` and a list of `ys` (in plain Julia) that you think might make a difficult-to-disambiguate dataset. You can then pass your `xs` and `ys` into the `do_inference` function defined earlier in the notebook, to see what the system concludes about your dataset. Note that the `do_inference` function constructs a *constraint* choicemap that constrains each `(:y, i)` to the value `ys[i]` from the dataset you passed in. This works because `(:y, i)` is always the name of the ith datapoint, no matter the value of `:is_line`.

**Updating / manipulating traces**

You write:

> I'd expect to be able to introspect sine/line_model's trace from within combo, and do element-wise addition on the traces to get a new trace. And not have to randomly pick a number close to :intercept, :phase, etc. so I can include it in my trace later on.

You can certainly call `simulate` twice to get two traces, outside a generative function like `combo`. But traces cannot be manipulated in arbitrary ways (e.g. "elementwise addition"): as data structures, traces maintain certain invariants, like always knowing the exact probability of their current values under the model that generated them, and always holding values that actually could have been generated from the model.

The dictionary-like data structure you're looking for is a choicemap. Choicemaps are mutable and can be built up to include arbitrary values at arbitrary addresses. For example, you can write:

```
observations = Gen.choicemap()
for (i, y) in enumerate(ys)
  observations[(:y, i)] = y
end
```

Choicemaps can be used as constraints to generate new traces (using `Gen.generate`), as arguments to Gen's low-level `Gen.update` method (with allows you to update a trace while recomputing any relevant probabilities, and erroring if your updates are invalid), and in several other places.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Alex Lew's clarification, the answer is much simpler than I was making it out to be. Here's what I did:

```
xs = [-5:0.1;5;]

ambiguous = [0.3*x+0.2*sin(x)+normal(0,.5) for x in xs];

ambig_trace = do_inference(combined_model,xs, ambiguous, 100)

render_combined(ambig_trace)
```

producing:

[image: ambiguous trace]

(or something more sinusoidal, if that was inferred)

Then finally:

```
n_infers = 100
is_sine = 0
for i=1:n_infers
    curr_trace = do_inference(combined_model, xs, ambiguous, 100)
    if !curr_trace[:is_line] is_sine+=1 end
end
println("posterior probability of sine wave model is $(is_sine/n_infers)")

# => posterior probability of sine wave model is 0.52
```